# CRM 2013 Quick Create Form not opening

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm facing an issue where my Quick Create forms for CRM2013 are no longer opening. What happens is that the header part of the form appears (displaying the name of the entity and the close icon) but nothing else happens.

The form doesn't open, no matter how long I wait. Once I close this quick create form, I get an error from CRM with the following message:

"Unable to set value of the property onRefreshFormSaveCallback"

In Developer Tools, the exception seems to be thrown from a file called JsProvider.ashx

Here is the full dump:

Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error Report Contents

```
<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onRefreshFormSaveCallback' of undefined</Message>
   <Line>10601</Line>
   <URL>/_common/JsProvider.ashx?IsRefreshForm=true&ids=1759665639-1968334880-1039841082-1793205875-1314140682-1547461133-1992083491-1000289424-159335543-542820515-1946640899-1603536461-1264077421-374257838&ver=1052389390</URL>
   <PageURL>/_forms/read/page.aspx?_CreateFromId=%7b152C481E-BF12-E411-80BF-00155D148504%7d&_CreateFromType=10007&_searchText=undefined&businessRulesVersion=1033&etc=10013&formts=474159&hidecommandbar=true&mdts=-14853627&setLastViewed=false&showglobalquickcreate=true&userts=130506518819432115</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymousr:Cannotsetproperty'onRefreshFormSaveCallback'ofundefined</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymousr:Cannotsetproperty'onRefreshFormSaveCallback'ofundefined</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>undefined</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>undefined</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>undefined</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1920x1080</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>
   <ClientTime>2014-07-24T15:06:04</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>
    <OrgCulture>3081</OrgCulture>
    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>
    <UserCulture>3081</UserCulture>
    <OrgID>{FDEC9D90-233C-443B-866F-57D7DA67A40E}</OrgID>
    <UserID>{A2FAA665-0DE2-E311-80B8-00155DC8811F}</UserID>
    <CRMVersion>6.0.2.51</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - one of the other developers had created a format function directly on the string object

```
String.format = function() {...}
```

This seemed to mess something up in CRM 2013. Once I removed that declaration, everything went back to normal